# XCTest Unit and UI tests for AWS Device Farm

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, aws-device-farm

I'm trying to set up our iOS XCTest to run on AWS Device Farm, but it seems no matter how I build and upload them, the tests will always give error and failed every time. They successfully execute when i run through the XCode, but do not run on AWS Device Farm.

I tried even from very simple app without any api call that was also failed.

Here is the error that appears in AWS Device Farm's interface.

[You can see Logs from here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2FvgIb537bkdF9HLXNOMTg4MEE)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing while I am getting the error is archive the project and then exporting it and generating the ipa but when I change the method of generating ipa and follow below one, my tests run successfully

**1.Go into build directory: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos**

**2.Create a new directory named "Payload"**

**3.Move the appName.app folder into the "Payload" folder**

**4.Zip the "Payload" folder and give it a .ipa extension**

[image]